# Jquery datepicker max setting

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have to set max date to last date of previous month, on and after 15th of the current month.
I am able to get the last date of previous month but how do I get the last date of previous month only after 15 of current month.

**for eg:**

If today is 14 of November then max date in datepicker should be 30th of September else today is 15 of November then max date in datepicker should be 31st of October.

How can I update my code to achieve this.

```
var maxDate = new Date();
maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth()-0, 0);
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,  
      changeYear:true, 
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',

        minDate: new Date(2013, 3, 1),
        maxDate: maxDate,
        beforeShow: function(){    
           $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 10) 
                },
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
      $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
       }
       });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({      
      changeMonth: true,   
      changeYear:true,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',

        minDate: new Date(2013, 3, 1),
        maxDate: maxDate,
        beforeShow: function(){    
           $(".ui-datepicker").css('font-size', 10) 
                },
      onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yyyy');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written a method called **`getMaxDate()`**, which returns the **`maxdate`** based on the following conditions,

## Condition 1

today's date is < 15, then `maxDate` will be *today's month -2 and last date of that month.*

## Condition 2

today's date is >= 15, then `maxDate` will be *today's month -1 and last date of that month.*

```
function getMaxDate() {
    var today = new Date();
    var max = new Date();
    if (today.getDate() < 15) {
        max.setMonth(max.getMonth() - 1, 0);        
    } else {
        max.setMonth(max.getMonth() - 0, 0);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Then call it like

```
maxDate = getMaxDate();
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: i have added the function u created and called it,but it doesnt work any suggestions?? $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      changeMonth: true,  
      changeYear:true, 
   dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
   minDate: new Date(2013, 3, 1),
        maxDate: getMaxDate,

Comment: @user2911353 sorry for the typo, I have corrected it.  Check now.

Comment: Praveen i am bit lost in the two code pieces,can u pls point out what change have u made and where,thanks

Comment: @user2911353 check my revisions http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20209474/revisions :)

Comment: Thanks Praveen its awesome

Comment: what if we have to get date in #to  only dates more that 1month.eg if #from date is 15 oct 2015 #to date should only be between 15 oct 2015 to 15 nov 15